# How to compute the factors in Bezout's Identity

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

If I have two polynomials $p(x),q(x)$, `PolynomialGCD[p,q,x]` can give me their greatest common divisor. But how to compute the polynomials $a(x),b(x)$ such that $d(x)=a(x)p(x)+b(x)q(x)$? I'm having trouble programming the division algorithm, but if someone is able to do that, I might be able to reverse engineer the steps to build a,b.

Comment: Check out [`PolynomialExtendedGCD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialExtendedGCD)

Answer (score 2):

Use `PolynomialExtendedGCD`. Here's an example from the Mathematica documentation:

```
{f, g} = {2 x^5 - 2 x, (x^2 - 1)^2};
{d, {a, b}} = PolynomialExtendedGCD[f, g, x]
d == {f, g}.{a, b} // Simplify
```